# Oracle sql - global variable

Tags: sql, global-variables

I have two sql script file which are to be scheduled as windows tasks. 
1.sql contains this at the begining:
    column dat1 new_value DAY_NUMBER;
    select 2 dat1 from dual;

While 2.sql contains this at the begining:
    column dat1 new_value DAY_NUMBER;
    select 1 dat1 from dual;

If I am going to combine this two script into one, will DAY_NUMBER be set to 1?

Thanks a lot.

Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'll generate an error:

```
column dat1 new_value DAY_NUMBER; select 2 dat1 from dual;

column dat1 new_value DAY_NUMBER; select 1 dat1 from dual;
```

The error is that you'll have the same column variable **dat1** declared twice.